# python is there a way to set a default value to an arguent to be another arguement in the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to build a matix class for practice, and i was wondering, suppose I define a matrix with the arguements "rows" and "columns".
is there a way to set "columns" to be "rows" as default?
example:`def __init__(self, rows, columns = rows)`
i tried to compile but it gives me the "unresolved refence" error
thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not work. But you can set `None` as default and check for that in the method's body, e.g.

```
def __init__(self, rows, columns=None):
    if columns is None:
        columns = rows
    # do something
```

Comment: Although you can argue that you don't check for rows either, that is the disadvantage of a weak type system.

Comment: This referred to a deleted comment.